# python tkinter get value but it just gets " <built-in function input>"

Tags: python, tkinter

my code is

```
# Importing Libraries
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
from firebase import firebase
cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccount.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"
firestore_db = firestore.client()
class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        # configure window
        self.title("CustomTkinter complex_example.py")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        # create main entry and button
        self.entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text="Enter Your Message")
        self.entry.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=(20, 0), pady=(20, 20), sticky="nsew")
        input = self.entry.get()
        self.main_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, text="Sent", fg_color="transparent", border_width=2, command=sent, text_color=("gray10", "#DCE4EE"))
        self.main_button_1.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=(20, 20), pady=(20, 20), sticky="nsew")





def sent():
    print(input)
    
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

i typed "123test" it prints "
" so idk
and i finds codes and github but no ans
github https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkEntry#get

so i tryed to get input

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of wrong things in your code:

1. You are naming your variable `input`, which is the name of a build-in function of python (that is used to take user input from the console). This is called "shadowing", and python will get confused at what you want to refer to so do not call your variable `input`. Avoid doing that, by any means.
2. You are getting the content of the text when creating the window, not after. So here no matter what, your code will never get what you have written, only the empty string at creation.
3. Your `sent` function is not in the context of the class, that is wrong too. Here is what you should be doing:

```py
class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        # configure window
        self.title("CustomTkinter complex_example.py")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        # create main entry and button
        self.entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text="Enter Your Message")
        self.entry.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=(20, 0), pady=(20, 20), sticky="nsew")
        self.main_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, text="Sent", fg_color="transparent", border_width=2, command=self.sent, text_color=("gray10", "#DCE4EE"))
        self.main_button_1.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=(20, 20), pady=(20, 20), sticky="nsew")



    def sent(self):
        entry_content = self.entry.get()
        print(entry_content)
```

By indenting the `sent` function and passing the argument `self`, you can access the content of `self.entry` whenever you click the button, and then do something with that content. Do not forget to write `self.sent` instead of just `sent` in the `command` property of the `self.main_button_1`.